# Dividing a column cell with a different number based on number of observations in a panel long format

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data which is of a panel structure. I need to normalize each cell so that the observation for a country is divided by total number of observations for that country divided by total number of observations in the panel structure (here 10 - in my data 1100). Also I have showcased three countries (AL, UK, FR) but I have 92 in total so I need some general formula (mutate: by = country?).

This is my data

```
df1 <- data_frame(Country = 
                    c("AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL",
                      "UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK",
                      "FR","FR","FR","FR","FR","FR","FR","FR","FR","FR"),
               Obs = c(NA,NA,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,NA,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,NA))
df1

 Country   Obs
   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 AL         NA
 2 AL         NA
 3 AL          2
 4 AL          3
 5 AL          2
 6 AL          3
 7 AL          2
 8 AL          3
 9 AL          2
10 AL         NA
11 UK          1
12 UK          2
13 UK          1
14 UK          2
15 UK          1
16 UK          2
17 UK          1
18 UK          2
19 UK          1
20 UK          2
21 FR         NA
22 FR         NA
23 FR         NA
24 FR         NA
25 FR         NA
26 FR         NA
27 FR         NA
28 FR         NA
29 FR          4
30 FR         NA
```

Now, what I want is to divide each cell with  *number of observations available for each country / total obs* like so,

```
  df2 <-   data_frame(Country = 
                           c("AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL",
                             "UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK",
                             "FR","FR","FR","FR","FR","FR","FR","FR","FR","FR"),
                        Obs = c(NA,NA,2*7/10,3*7/10,2*7/10,3*7/10,2*7/10,3*7/10,2*7/10,
                               NA,1*10/10,2*10/10,1*10/10,2*10/10,1*10/10,2*10/10,1*10/10,
                                2*10/10,1*10/10,2*10/10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4*1/10,NA))

df2

  Country   Obs
   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 AL       NA  
 2 AL       NA  
 3 AL        1.4
 4 AL        3.7
 5 AL        2.7
 6 AL        3.7
 7 AL        2.7
 8 AL        3.7
 9 AL        2.7
10 AL       NA  
11 UK        1  
12 UK        2  
13 UK        1  
14 UK        2  
15 UK        1  
16 UK        2  
17 UK        1  
18 UK        2  
19 UK        1  
20 UK        2  
21 FR       NA  
22 FR       NA  
23 FR       NA  
24 FR       NA  
25 FR       NA  
26 FR       NA  
27 FR       NA  
28 FR       NA  
29 FR        0.4
30 FR       NA
```

I am interested in solving the problem obviously BUT I would **really really** appreciate it if you could show me how to do this for multiple columns as my original data needs this same operation done for many columns where the country tickers (AL, UK, FR in example) remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(Obs = Obs * sum(!is.na(Obs))/n()) %>%
  ungroup

#  Country   Obs
#   <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 AL       NA  
# 2 AL       NA  
# 3 AL        1.4
# 4 AL        2.1
# 5 AL        1.4
# 6 AL        2.1
# 7 AL        1.4
# 8 AL        2.1
# 9 AL        1.4
#10 AL       NA  
# … with 20 more rows
```

`sum(!is.na(Obs))` counts number of non-NA values in the `Country` whereas `n()` gives the number of rows for the `Country`.

For multiple columns -

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(across(col1:col4, ~. * sum(!is.na(.))/n())) %>%
  ungroup
```

This will be applied to `col1` to `col4` in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Obs := Obs * mean(!is.na(Obs)), County]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(Obs = Obs * mean(!is.na(Obs)))
```